# problem with parsing youtube xml in iphone application

Tags: iphone

Greeting,
         I am working around youtube in my application.i get the responce like below
   /---------------

```
enter code here



  <entry>
<id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5iVl6iPODmM</id>
<published>2010-10-05T11:02:36.000Z</published>
<updated>2010-10-05T22:28:54.000Z</updated>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat' term='Entertainment' label='Entertainment'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Rusty'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='horse trainer'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Jacob Rhodes'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Secretariat'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Penny Chenery'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Jennifer Smart'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Gary Stevens'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='jockey'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='William Nack'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Otto Thorwarth'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Sean Michael Cunningham'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Willa Baker'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Dylan Baker'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='AJ Michalka'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Diane Lane'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Mark Ciardi'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Margo Martindale'/>
<title type='text'>Secretariat Red Carpet by Jennifer Smart</title>
<content type='text'>I've seen a lot of things on the red carpet, including a variety of animals, but this is the first time I've seen a real horse at a movie premiere! I enjoyed speaking with the actors and movie makers, and I learned a lot about Secretariat and the inspiring story about this Triple Crown winner beating the odds.</content>
<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iVl6iPODmM&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
<link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5iVl6iPODmM/responses'/>
<link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5iVl6iPODmM/related'/>
<link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile' type='text/html' href='http://m.youtube.com/details?v=5iVl6iPODmM'/>
<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/JenSmartTV/uploads/5iVl6iPODmM'/>
<author>
     <name>JenSmartTV</name>
     <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/jensmarttv</uri>
</author>
<gd:comments><gd:feedLink href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5iVl6iPODmM/comments' countHint='0'/></gd:comments>
<yt:location>Hollywood, CA</yt:location>
<media:group>
    <media:category label='Entertainment' scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>Entertainment</media:category>
    <media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/5iVl6iPODmM?f=user_uploads&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'             medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='547' yt:format='5'/>
     <media:content url='rtsp://v1.cache5.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwljDs4j6mUl5hMYDSANFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/      3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='547' yt:format='1'/>
     <media:content url='rtsp://v6.cache2.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwljDs4j6mUl5hMYESARFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/      3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='547' yt:format='6'/>
     <media:description type='plain'>I've seen a lot of things on the red carpet, including a variety of animals, but this is the first time        I've seen a real horse at a movie premiere! I enjoyed speaking with the actors and movie makers, and I learned a lot about Secretariat and  the inspiring story about this Triple Crown winner beating the odds.</media:description>
     <media:keywords>Rusty, horse trainer, Jacob Rhodes,    Secretariat, Penny Chenery, Jennifer Smart, Gary Stevens, jockey, William Nack,         Otto Thorwarth, Sean Michael Cunningham, Willa Baker, Dylan     Baker, AJ Michalka, Diane Lane, Mark Ciardi, Margo Martindale</    media:keywords>
    <media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iVl6iPODmM&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player'/>
     <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5iVl6iPODmM/2.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:04:33.500'/>
     <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5iVl6iPODmM/1.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:02:16.750'/>
     <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5iVl6iPODmM/3.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:06:50.250'/>
     <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5iVl6iPODmM/0.jpg' height='240' width='320' time='00:04:33.500'/>
     <media:title type='plain'>Secretariat Red Carpet by Jennifer Smart</media:title>
     <yt:duration seconds='547'/>
</media:group>
<yt:recorded>2010-09-30</yt:recorded>
<yt:statistics favoriteCount='0' viewCount='60'/>
</entry>
```

//-------------
now i want to get the values for media:thumbnail ,media:content url

i am using the LIBXML2 parsing.
Kindly help!
Thanx in advance!!!i`enter code here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the JSON format of the feed? You can add `?alt=json` to the URL to get the JSON version of it (for example, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5iVl6iPODmM?alt=json). Then you can use a JSON library (such as this one: http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) to parse it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeap, that's what I did as well. I used touchJSON for that, super simple